# Multiple MILP solutions in ORTOOLS [python]

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools, scip, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to use or-tools in Python to solve a mixed-integer linear program that has multiple optimal solutions.  However, `NextSolution()` always returns `False`, so I cannot retrieve more than one solution. I understand that this function works using a constraint solver, but I would like to use the MILP solver.

The related [or-tools documentation](https://google.github.io/or-tools/cpp_linear/classoperations__research_1_1MPSolver.html#a18daa488abaa904f23c8f74158290883) states:

> As of 2020-02-10, only Gurobi and SCIP support NextSolution(), see linear_solver_interfaces_test for an example of how to configure these solvers for multiple solutions. Other solvers return false unconditionally.

However, I cannot find any such linear_solver_interfaces_test in the source repo, documentation, or via a web search.  I am using ortools version 7.8.7959 and the included SCIP 7.0.1 with Python 3.6.9.

Below is my example code which illustrates a simple example of the type I would like to solve.  It should produce three unique solutions, but currently produces zero solutions.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

def main():
    solver = pywraplp.Solver("multiple_solution_test", pywraplp.Solver.SCIP_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
    x = solver.IntVar(0, 2, "x")
    y = solver.IntVar(0, 2, "y")
    z = solver.IntVar(0, 2, "z")
    solver.Add(x + y <= 2)
    solver.Maximize(x + y + z)  # should be 4, which can be obtained by (2,0,2), (1,1,2), or (0,2,2)
    solver.Solve()
    print_solutions(solver, x, y, z)


def print_solutions(solver, x, y, z):
    count = 0
    
    while solver.NextSolution():  # <-- NextSolution() always returns False!
        count += 1
        print("x =", x.solution_value(), "y =", y.solution_value(), "z =", z.solution_value())
    print("\nNumber of solutions found:", count)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the misleading documentation.
Currently, only Gurobi supports NextSolution. I have not exported the SCIP relevant code.

If your problem only needs Boolean or integer variable, you can use the CP-SAT (ortools/sat) solver that supports enumerating over multiple solutions.

see this [documentation](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/solver.md).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense!  It is certainly desirable to have the SCIP interface for this, since I can then export code that does not require purchase of a Gurobi license, but I can use Gurobi for now in order to test and prototype.  Thank you for your timely response.